# Need some help in Java String

Tags: java, string

I am having a string in java like

```
String str="gudmor,ningeveryone,Have a great day,thankssssssssssss";
```

I need to split the string, if its length is more than 10 and with the deliemeter `","`. If the 10th character in the staring is not "," then I have to take split the string from the previous occurrence of `","` with in length 10.

For the above set of string, I need the output like,

```
 gudmor

 ningeveryo

 ne

 Have a gre

 at day

 thanksssss

 sssssss
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Some documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood you well but try following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String input = "gudmor,ningeveryone,Have a great day,thankssssssssssss";
        String[] firstSplit = input.split(",");
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] tmpArray;
        for (String elem : firstSplit) {
            if (elem.length() <= 10) {
                result.add(elem);
            } else {
                for(int i = 0;i < elem.length()/10;i++) {
                    result.add(elem.substring(i*10,(i+1)*10));
                }
                if(elem.length() % 10 != 0) {
                    result.add(elem.substring(elem.length() - (elem.length() % 10)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```